# In the Node js How to Users should be restricted to a defined number of login attempts per unit of time

Tags: authentication, login-attempts

Users should be restricted to a defined number of login attempts per unit of time,
After the n number of unsuccesfull  login attemots user can be lock, this is for avoiding Brute Force Attack

Answer (score 1):

you can use [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) npm package.

```
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const limiter = rateLimit({
            windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
            max: 100, // Limit each IP to 100 requests per `window` (here, per 15 minutes)
            standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
            legacyHeaders: false, // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
            message: "You exceeded 100 requests in 15 minutes limit!",
        });
    
 // Apply the rate limiting middleware to all requests
 app.use(limiter);
```

you can also use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package with Redis..

also you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690950/preventing-brute-force-using-node-and-express-js)